# PHP Easy way to combine PHP if statement with HTML

Tags: php

This probably might be a silly question, but what I am trying to do is to make an if statement to do the following:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['login'] == true) { ?>
Display this HTML code (without converting it to PHP echos
<?php } else { ?>
Display this instead
<?php } ?>
```

Or will I need to echo, and in turn escape all the required characters in order to do what I am after.

Thanks

Comment: If the question is "Will this work?" … try it and see.

Comment: In your example code you're missing the closing bracket. This ?> should be this:  <?php } ?>

Comment: You might want to search a bit for the term ViewHelper as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just try it out. But for the record, this works. And is in fact an idiomatic way of solving this.

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['login']) { ?> 
  <p>Display this HTML code</p>
<?php } else { ?> 
  <p>Display this instead</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Indented for readability (however, this messes with the HTML structure indentation so maybe it’s not appropriate).

Alternatively, the [following style](http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) is often used because the lone brace at the end gets lonely:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['login']): ?> 
  <p>Display this HTML code</p>
<?php else: ?> 
  <p>Display this instead</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

(In both cases I’ve removed the `== true` from the conditional because it’s utterly redundant. Don’t write `== true`.)

Comment: You're missing the `<?php` at the start of the last line of both those examples...

Comment: Ah, too slow! =) Great answer btw, +1

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [HEREDOC or NOWDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) syntax

```
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['login']) { 
   $html =<<<HTML
Add HTML here
HTML;
   echo $html;
} else { 
   $other_html =<<<'OTHERHTML'
Add HTML here
OTHERHTML;
   echo $other_html;
?>
```

Comment: I can't stand the lack of readability with both HEREDOC and NOWDOC syntaxes.  To me that just looks like a jumble of code that you need to read line by line to figure out what's going on (Especially since you can't use proper indenting with the syntax).  Whereas a traditional structure (as in the question) is much more readable with a quick scan.  I'm not going to -1 for it (since it is a valid alternative), but I think it's worth saying that I think it's a bad alternative...

Comment: I admit there are some quarks with the HERE/NOW DOC syntax structure, thanx for the constructive criticism as I will keep this in mind in future projects. It's always good to hear honest answers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works.

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['login'] == true) { ?>
   <span>hello</span>
<?php } else { ?>
   <span>going already?</span>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use if and endif

```
<?php if ( expression ) : ?>
<p>some message here</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>other message</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything not in PHP tags will be outputted as HTML anyway, so your original code will work fine.

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['login'] == true) { ?> 
<a href="logout.html">Log Out</a> 
<?php } else { ?> 
<a href="login.html">Login</a>  
<?php } ?>
```